# Show different footer depending if page is protected or not - Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, code-snippets

So, I implemented a protected area on my Website (with umbraco) which has a Login when you want to access a page that normal users don't have access to. I am using the Login Snippet and the Login Status Snippet Macro that umbraco provides.

Like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
         @Umbraco.RenderMacro("MembersLoginStatus")
    </div>
</div>
```

I am showing it on the footer but right now it is always visible but I only want it to be visible when you are on a page that is protected.

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what version of umbraco are you using? latest?

Comment: instead of checking if the page is protected, you can check if there is someone logged in; if they're not then show the login button otherwise, don't

Comment: Yes I am using the version, 7.4.3

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply verified if he is Logged in or not. Using the Umbraco Macro Snippet it is quite easy to find out.

```
@if (Umbraco.MemberIsLoggedOn())
{
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
           @Umbraco.RenderMacro("MembersLoginStatus")
      </div>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: that's a bit cheeky

Comment: Why do you think that?